# $.ajaxSetup change response $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I make an ajax call with $.post, I want to have some base settings already set so I do not need to put it in my code every time I want to use $.post.
I've done this like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataType    :"json", // all requests should respond with json string by default
    type        : "POST", // all request should POST by default
    beforeSend  : function(){
        this.url = basepath+"include/ajax/"+this.url; // before making the request, change url location to ajax folder
    },
    error       : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        displayMessage("error", "Request could not be completed: <pre>"+errorThrown+"</pre>", true);
    },
    success : function(event){
    console.log(event);
        if(event.responseJSON !== undefined && event.responseJSON.status !== undefined && event.responseJSON.status === true){
            if(event.responseJSON.output === undefined){
                console.log("something is wrong 1");
                displayMessage("error", "Property output was not found in response.");
            }
            else{
                event.responseJSON.status = false;
                console.log("something is wrong 2");
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log("something is wrong 3");
        }
    },
    done    : function(){
        console.log("done");
    },
    always  : function(){
        console.log("always");
    }
});
```

I make my $.post like this:

```
$("div#brandsView button.compose").click(function(e){
    $.post("brands.php",{method:"composeMessage",data:{brand:brandId}},function(data){
        console.log(data)
    })
});
```

Now I'm running into a problem:
I want to alter the response from "brands.php" in $.ajaxSetup before it comes to $.post. As you can see, I've tried to functions like success and complete, but those won't alter the result in $.post.
Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to do so?

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: _“I want to alter the response from "brands.php" in $.ajaxSetup before it comes to $.post.”_ – I have no idea what that is supposed to mean. Altering the response before it is received? Makes no sense. Altering the data after it is received? OK, what’s the problem with that?

Comment: With $.post you can provide your own .success function.
I want $.ajaxSetup to alter the data that is send to .success in the $.post.

Comment: Still don’t understand what your actual problem is here.

Comment: That I can't catch the results in $.ajax and then apss it on to $.post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success handler in your `$.post` overrides the one in your `$.ajaxSetup`. You should extract the success handler definition from your `ajaxSetup` :

```
function handleSuccess(event){
    console.log(event);
        if(event.responseJSON !== undefined && event.responseJSON.status !== undefined && event.responseJSON.status === true){
            if(event.responseJSON.output === undefined){
                console.log("something is wrong 1");
                displayMessage("error", "Property output was not found in response.");
            }
            else{
                event.responseJSON.status = false;
                console.log("something is wrong 2");
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log("something is wrong 3");
        }
    }
```

then have your `$.ajaxSetup` like this :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataType    :"json", // all requests should respond with json string by default
    type        : "POST", // all request should POST by default
    beforeSend  : function(){
        this.url = basepath+"include/ajax/"+this.url; // before making the request, change url location to ajax folder
    },
    error       : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        displayMessage("error", "Request could not be completed: <pre>"+errorThrown+"</pre>", true);
    },
    success : handleSuccess,
    done    : function(){
        console.log("done");
    },
    always  : function(){
        console.log("always");
    }
});
```

then have your `$.post` like this :

```
$.post("brands.php",{method:"composeMessage",data:{brand:brandId}},function(data){
        handleSuccess(data);
        console.log(data);
    })
```